# Angular momentum of a uniform circular disc about an axis inclined with respect to the symmetry axis

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

The question is: Finding the angular momentum of a uniform circular disk of Mass $M$ and radius $R$ is rotating with angular speed $w$ about an axis, 60 degrees inclined with respect to its symmetry axis. (The answer is $\sqrt{7}wMr^2/8)$

So a bit of trial and error and i got the answer. The problem is **I dont know why the method gave the correct answer**.

For a Uniform disc in xy plane 
$$I_{zz}=0.5 MR^2$$
$$I_{xx}=I_{yy}=0.25 MR^2$$

For the new axis which is 60 degree inclined to the z axis. I took components of $I_{zz},I_{xx},I_{yy}$ along this axis.

$$I_1=I_{zz}\cos60, I_2=I_{xx}\cos30, I_3=I_{yy}\cos90$$
The $I$ about new axis = $(I_1^2+I_2^2+I_3^2)^{0.5}$ 
which gives me $\sqrt{7} MR^2/8$
Multiply that by $w$ and I get the correct answer

Why did this work? Where can I study this theory from? Any books or lectures?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! The equations become much easier to read, search and edit when [mathjax](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5610/75633) is used. It'd be great if you could use it in your next posts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Definitely will do that from the next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most general form of angular momentum for rigid bodies is this:
$$ \vec L = \mathbf{I} \, \vec \omega $$
where $\mathbf{I}$ is a 3x3 matrix called the *intertia tensor*. This only reduces to $\vec L = I \vec \omega$ when $\vec \omega$ is along a principle axis **and** there are no $I_{xy},I_{xz},I_{yz}$ terms. Concerning your problem, 
$$\mathbf{I} = \begin{pmatrix} MR^2/4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & MR^2/4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & MR^2/2\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$ \vec \omega = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \omega \sin{60}  \\ \omega \cos{60}\end{pmatrix}$$
Since we are at liberty to choose either the x-axis or the y-axis to be aligned with $\vec \omega$, I chose the y-axis.  Multiplying $\vec \omega$ by $\mathbf{I}$ will give you $\vec L$, and taking the magnitude of $|\vec L|$ will give you 
$$ | \vec L| = \frac{\sqrt{7}}{8}MR^2 \omega $$